# Template function with multiple parameters of same type

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic

I'm trying to create a function that can take multiple parameters of the same type, passed in as a template. The number of arguments is known in compile time:

```
struct Foo
{
    int a, b, c;
};

template <uint32_t argsCount, typename T>
void fun(T ...args) // max number of args == argsCount
{
    // ...
    // std::array<T, argsCount>{ args... };
}

int main()
{
    fun<3, Foo>( { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } );

    // Dont want to do:
    // fun( Foo{}, Foo{}, Foo{} );
    // nor:
    // fun<Foo, Foo, Foo>( ... );

    return 0;
}
```

I must take into consideration these constraints:

- no heap memory allocations
- no va_args

Is it possible to do something similar in C++14 (preferably C++14, but curious what are the solutions in newer versions)?

edit: cleaned up the initial sloppy pseudcode.

Comment: Note that `typename T` should be `typename... T`

Comment: Something == Foo?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're excluding `fun( Someting{}, Something{}, Something{} )`?  That seems like a rather elegant call, and it takes advantage of template deduction.

Comment: `fun( std::array<Foo, 3>{{ 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 }} );`?

Comment: @AnoopRana All linked dupes are irrelevant to this question - OP wants to specify the type `Foo` only *once*. I don't think it's possible with variadic templates.

Comment: @Evg The same was done in the linked dupes. For once, read the OP's question carefully *"I'm trying to create a function that can take multiple parameters of the same type,"*.

Comment: @AnoopRana I've read it, and you didn't. Just show me how a variadic template implementation could work with specifying a type only once. `class... T` is irrelevant here, because those `T...` can't be deduced from braced lists `{...}`.

Comment: Some dupes: [dupe1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703658/specifying-one-type-for-all-arguments-passed-to-variadic-function-or-variadic-te), [dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528801/c-parameter-pack-constrained-to-have-instances-of-a-single-type), [dupe3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71733467/c-multiple-function-parameters-with-varargs-of-a-specific-type), [dupe4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71820825/c-function-with-a-viariable-number-of-arguments-of-a-certain-type)

Comment: @Evg If tomorrow someone ask a new question with the same description as this one except that in that new question they write *"by specifying two types"* then that doesn't make it a completely new question. The concept is the same in both cases. If one understands the former they'll be able to understand the latter.

Comment: @AnoopRana OP explicitly stated what they *don't want to do* in the question. That requirement is an essential part of this question. All those dupes don't satisfy this requirement. Have are they dupes then?

Comment: From all the dups, only 2 of their answers matches OP needed (similar answer than Yakk - Adam Nevraumont's one).

Comment: Why don't you accept an std::array<T, N> instead of varadic arguments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you change the function into a functor, you can introduce a parameter pack in the body of the type of the functor.

First create a helper to turn `<N, T>` -> `std::tuple<T, T, T, ..., T>` (`N` times):

```cpp
template<std::size_t N, typename T>
struct repeat {
private:
    // enable_if<true, T> == type_identity<T>
    template<std::size_t... I>
    static std::enable_if<true, std::tuple<std::enable_if_t<I==I, T>...>>
    get(std::index_sequence<I...>);
public:
    using type = typename decltype(get(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}))::type;
};
```

Then have your functor take a `std::tuple<Args...>`, where `Args` will be a parameter pack with `T` `N` times:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename Args>
struct fun_t;

template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct fun_t<T, std::tuple<Args...>> {
    static constexpr std::size_t argsCount = sizeof...(Args);

    void operator()(Args... args) const {
        // ...
        // std::array<T, argsCount>{ args... };
    }
};

template<std::uint32_t argCount, typename T>
constexpr fun_t<T, typename repeat<argCount, T>::type> fun;


int main() {
    fun<3, Foo>({ 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 });
}
```

Answer (score 9):

With a slightly different syntax on the call site, you could do it by taking a reference to an array:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void fun(const T(& args)[N]) {
    auto args_as_stdarray = std::to_array(args);
}

fun<Foo>({{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
template <class T0, class...Ts,
  std::enable_if_t< std::is_same_v<T0, Ts> && ..., bool > =true
>
void fun(T0 arg0, Ts ...args)
{
  constexpr auto argsCount = sizeof...(args)+1;
  std::array<T0, argsCount>{ arg0, args... };
}
```

this is [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17); it could be done in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), it would just require more typing and I am lazy (replacing the fold expression mainly).

This requires the call site have `Foo`s, which you don't want.

```
template<std::size_t I, class T>
struct helper { using type = T; };
template<std::size_t I, class T>
using X = typename helper<I,T>::type;

template<class T, std::size_t...Is>
void fun(std::index_sequence<Is...>, X<Is, T>... ts) {
  std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> args(ts...);
}
```

use:

```
fun<Foo>( std::make_index_sequence<7>, /* 7 Foo objects */ );
```

we can also do:

```
fun<Foo, 7>()( /* 7 Foo objects */ );
```

with a slight change:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N> 
auto fun() {
  auto seq = std::make_index_sequence<N>{};
  return []<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return [](X<Is, Foo>... ts) {
      std::array<Foo, sizeof...(Is)> args{ts...};
    };
  }( seq );
}
```

this is [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), but you can backport to [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) by writing argument pack unpackers.

The trick here is that `foo<Foo,7>()` returns a function object that knows it takes `7` `Foo` objects exactly.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/xdWM4eKf9).

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), we can:

```
template<class T, class Pack>
struct fun_impl;
template<class T, std::size_t...Is>
struct fun_impl<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
  void operator()(X<Is, T>... ts)const {
    std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> args{ts...};
  }
};
template<class T, std::size_t N>
auto fun() {
  return fun_impl<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>{};
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/8d3d36fEG) (based off @Jarod42's version below).

Comment: This will require to use `Foo{...}` for each argument on the call site.

Comment: @Evg good point.  Alternative added.

Comment: Interesting approach. Upvoted.

Comment: @Jarod42 And now typos fixed.

Comment: C++14 alternative is not that long/complicated by using functor class [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8fj4WrTP6)

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah, I try to avoid additional bespoke helper types.  Probably unwisely.  :)